# How to combine three count queries into one

Tags: sql, database, count

How can I combine such a query here with two other queries, using a different reaction (`dislike`, `viewed`) so I can gather stats with one query?

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) FROM reactions 
    WHERE post_id = $1 AND reaction 'like';
```

Answer (score 2):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    user_id,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN reaction = 'like'    THEN 1 END) AS like_cnt,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN reaction = 'dislike' THEN 1 END) AS dislike_cnt,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN reaction = 'viewed'  THEN 1 END) AS viewed_cnt
FROM reactions
WHERE post_id = $1
GROUP BY user_id;
```

It was not entirely clear from your question whether you want these stats for a single user or over the entire table.  If the latter, then we can aggregate by the `user_id` and generate these stats for each user.

Comment: Sorry, for the entire table. Problem is, I need to work around duplicate entries a user can have reacted to a post with the same reaction over and over again but it should only be counted as one which is why I think the distinct is necessary

Comment: @Mahoni You never told us which database you are using, but try doing `COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ...)`

Answer (score 1):

I think like this one:

```
SELECT reaction,count(DISTINCT user_id) FROM reactions
WHERE post_id=$1 AND reaction in ('like','dislike','viewed')
GROUP BY reaction
```